# How to set up a network in Hyperledger fabric without using Docker Swarm or Kubernetes where peers are located in different physical machines?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to understand Networking in fabric using Kafka as the consensus type. How do I establish a fabric network in multiple physical machines using Kafka?

Answer (score -2):

You need to define extra hosts in docker configuration for the 2nd machine.

peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    extra_hosts:
     - "orderer.example.com:"
     - "peer0.org1.example.com:"
     - "peer1.org1.example.com:"
     - "cliOrg1:"
    networks:
      - byfn

peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org2.example.com
    extra_hosts:
     - "orderer.example.com:"
     - "peer0.org1.example.com:"
     - "peer1.org1.example.com:"
     - "cliOrg1:"
    networks:
      - byfn

Once peer nodes are up with this config, then send mychannel.block to peers of org2(on another machine ) to join that channel.